# Magento2.3.2: Unable to go to payment method, Stucked at shipping method

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.2

My website is : https://www.depoto.com

When i tried to checkot the product, Its not going to next step. After entered the address, its not going to payment method step. Its just loading only.

Please see the attachment:
[image]

Comment: Have you merged and minified JS files?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora No, I havent do this merge but suddenly its behaving like this